# Grid background image opacity issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a strange issue with a background image for a Grid layout. For some reason the ListPicker does not completely cover the image. Instead some opacity is applied... (Look at the gears icon in the picture)

[image: Gird background with opacity issue]

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush 
                        ImageSource="/BrewingApp;component/Images/icon_gears_big.png" 
                        AlignmentX="Right" 
                        AlignmentY="Bottom" 
                        Stretch="None" 
                        Opacity="0.5" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
                <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,12,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="More Stuff :-)"></TextBlock>
                <Rectangle
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Height="1" 
                        Stroke="Red" 
                        StrokeThickness="1" >
                </Rectangle>

                <toolkit:ListPicker
                    Header="Hop Formula"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding HopFormulaList}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding HopFormulaSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" OpacityMask="Blue" />

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does `OpacityMask="Blue"` refer to?

Comment: Sorry, I started playing around a little with different values... I did not really mean to use an OpacityMask. I guess I just forgot to remove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` and `ListPicker` are using the `PhoneTextBoxBrush` for their background. This brush uses the color `#BFFFFFFF`. That is, a white (FFFFFF) with a bit of transparency (BF). Hence your problem. One way to solve the issue is simply to change the background of those controls:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneTextBoxBrush" Color="#BEBEBE"/>
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Almost perfect, the border of the controls is still transparent. Do you know the color and property of the border as well? thx

Comment: Just check the source code of the ListPicker: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80285#1510300 `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>`. Then check the default WP7 theme to see the default value of the brush (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design\ThemeResources.xaml`). In this case, it uses the same brush as the background, so a `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />` should do the trick.